# Scroll Bar Issues Automatically Scrolling Down To The Last Control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scroll, scrollbar

Alright, I designed a form to fit onto the current screen size I use, with the form having a vertical scroll bar to view items further down on the form.

At the bottom of the form, I have a couple of checkboxes a user has to select before clicking the submit button.

Once the user hits the submit buttom, the user can't scroll back up to the beginning of the form. The user can scroll back up, but when they stop scroll, it scrolls to the bottom where the last checkbox was checked off.

I assume by checking this last checkbox is that's setting the focus of that control?

Any suggestions on how to fix the scrolling issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a note of the last scroll position, and reapply it on `Form_Activate`

Try this:

```
'' Declare at form level
Private LastAutoScrollPos As System.Drawing.Point

Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
    Me.AutoScrollPosition = LastAutoScrollPos
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.ScrollEventArgs) Handles Me.Scroll
    If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll Then
        LastAutoScrollPos = New Point(LastAutoScrollPos.X, e.NewValue)
    ElseIf e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll Then
        LastAutoScrollPos = New Point(e.NewValue, LastAutoScrollPos.Y)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Would this work if your scroll bar is associated with a panel control?

Comment: I haven't tested this with Panel control, so can't give a definite answer at this moment. However I think this should work. Just give it a try and check.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. I decided to remove the panel I had and use the autoscroll on the form itself. Thanks again.